# JavaScript Broken Closures and Wrapper Function from John Resig #62 and #63

Tags: javascript

The first example below is #62 from John Resign`s Learning Advanced JavaScript http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#62. It is called Fix the Broken Closures.  Example 1 fails 4 times. Example 2, which is only different because it has a wrapper function, passes 4 times. It is example #63 from the same tutorial

Can someone please explain

1) why `i == count++` in example 1 fails.

2) why `i == count++` passes with the help of the wrapper function. How does the wrapper function change things to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

**Example 1**

```
var count = 0; 
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) { 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    assert( i == count++, "Check the value of i." ); 
  }, i * 200); 
}
```

**Example 2**

```
var count = 0; 
for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) (function(i){ 
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    assert( i == count++, "Check the value of i." ); 
  }, i * 200); 
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since `i` is being incremented in the loop the odds are strong that each time the `setTimeout` callback is invoked the value of `i` will be 4.
2. The wrapper function introduces a new scope allowing the value of the parameter `i` to maintain its value even though the surrounding `i` is being incremented by the loop.

---

```
function outerScope() {
    var x = 2, y = 3;

    function innerScope() {
        var x = 3;

        // Obviously this alerts 3.
        alert(x); 

        // Since we have no 'y' defined, alert the value 3 from the outer scope.
        alert(y); 
    }

    // Introduce a new scope.
    innerScope(); 

    // Since we have left the inner scope x is now 2.
    alert(x); 

    // Obviously this alerts 3.
    alert(y); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty straight forward.
Since setTimeout executes "asynchronously", there is no way of telling the exact value of i when the function executes, since the loop carries on running.

By using a function wrapper, effectively you are treating the body of the call as a function and are EXPLICITLY passing in the value of i.

You could clear this up by renaming the function i param to j or something else and update the innards of the function to from i to j

Basically it boils down to scoping